# Converting a class based view into a 'normal' view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have written the following django rest framework view:

```
# urls.py
url(r'user/company', views.UserViewSet.as_view({"get": "companyInfo"}), name="company_info"),

# views.py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    @action(methods=["get"], detail=True)
    def companyInfo(self, request):
        user = request.user
        company = user.get_company()
        detail = {}
        detail['company'] = company.name
        detail['num_users'] = company.num_licenses if company else None        
        return Response(detail)
```

How would I write this exact same view as a 'normal' django view with django rest framework. For example, something like this:

```
# urls.py
path('user/company/', views.company_info, name='company_info'),

# views.py
@require_GET
def company_info(request):
    user = request.user
    company = user.get_company()
    detail = {}
    detail['company'] = company.name
    detail['num_users'] = company.num_licenses if company else None        
    return Response(detail)
```

I suppose the above is a start, but I think I still need to authenticate properly (using jwt), which the `UserViewSet` is automatically doing with `permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)`.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal right I know my function is incomplete -- it has zero authentication here, so that's why I'm asking -- to see how to make it 'correct'.

Comment: by authentication you mean you want only those users to access the view who have signed in?

Comment: @VaibhavVishal correct, someone who's already been logged into the application directly (in django) or via jwt via the api

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close. You would want to add in two decorators to make this an authenticated API view like it is in the ClassView:

```
# path('user/company/', views.company_info, name='company_info'),

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
def company_info(request):
    user = request.user
    company = user.get_company()

    detail = {}
    detail['company'] = company.name
    detail['num_users'] = company.num_licenses if company else None
    detail['company_admin'] = company.admin_user.name if company else None

    return Response(detail)
```